# Accessing the object in a django admin template

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I'm overriding the change_form.html template and want to display links to other related objects.

When overriding an admin template, is there a way to access the object that is beeing edited in the template? Or perhaps pass that object to the template when registering it to the admin in some way?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

A quick look at django.contib.admin.options' change_view method shows the original object is included as a context variable called `original`. So if you're simply overriding change_form.html itself you can get to the object being edited via `{{ original }}`.

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/d25f3892114466d689fd6936f79f3bd9a9acc30e/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1886

That is where it is located in the change_view.
OSS is awesome.